# Breadcrumbs not showing properly translated

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

I am using a multilingual site with an Arabic and English versions. Before it was showing properly, but after the menu has been translated to Arabic, the breadcrumbs are showing only in Arabic.

How can I get the breadcrumbs in English too?

Answer (score 1):

the first you must check the node type that is not translated then you write the code like this

```
function YOURTHEM_breadcrumb(&$variables) {
  $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];
  $breadcrumb[] = drupal_get_title();
  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    $node = node_load(arg(1));
    $type = $node->type;
    if ($type) {
      switch ($type) {
        case 'conventions_exhibitions_director':
          $breadcrumb['breadcrumb']= l(t('Conventions Exhibitions Directory'), 'conventions-exhibitions-directory');
          break;
         case 'event':
          $breadcrumb['breadcrumb']= l(t('Event'), 'event');
          break;
         case 'news':
          $breadcrumb['breadcrumb']= l(t('News'), 'news');
          break;

      }


    //var_dump($breadcrumb);
      if($type == 'webform'){
        array_pop($breadcrumb);
        if (arg(0)== 'node' && arg(1) == 263){
           $breadcrumb['breadcrumb'] = t('Attend an Event');
        }elseif (arg(0)== 'node' && arg(1) == 7) {
          $breadcrumb['breadcrumb'] = t('Contact Us');
        }elseif (arg(0)== 'node' && arg(1) == 263 && arg(2) == 'done') {
          $breadcrumb['breadcrumb'] = t('Attend an Event');
        }elseif (arg(0)== 'node' && arg(1) == 7 && arg(2) == 'done') {
          var_dump($breadcrumb);
          $breadcrumb['breadcrumb'] = t('Contact Us');
        }
        $output .= '' . implode(' > ', $breadcrumb) . '';
        return $output;

      }
  }
    $output .= '' . implode(' > ', $breadcrumb) . '';
    return $output;
  }
}
```

be careful to replace the 'YOURTHEM' to your current them name